# How I get contain of a href and img from cgv website using axios and jsdom

Tags: axios, jsdom

I have a problem when i wanto target and get contain a href and img from this website *https://www.cgv.id/en/movies/now_playing* but i always wrong to get it. This is may code:

```
const { default: axios } = require("axios");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");

(async () => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          "https://www.cgv.id/en/movies/now_playing"
        );
        let dom = new JSDOM(data).window.document;
        let list = [...dom.getElementsByClassName('movie-list-body').querySelectorAll('li')]
        list = list.map(v => v.document.querySelectorAll('li a[href]').textContent.trimEnd())
        console.log(list);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})()
```

My code is error. How i repair it and can target to get contain  a href and img it?

Comment: Please never say you got an error.  **Cut & paste the exact error** so that we can see what it says.  If we can't see the error, we can't tell what the problem is.  It's like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "The car makes a noise" but not telling what the noise is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues with using `JSDOM` there, especially the way you are using it.

Firstly the website in question does not have any markup for the DOM element with the class name `movie-list-body` as you retrieve it using `Axios`

On further inspection I realised they are using a `jQuery` AJAX call to retrieve all the links and images from a `JSON` file.

Following is the script they are using to do so.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/en/loader/home_movie_list',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.movie-list-body').html(data.now_playing);
                $('.comingsoon-movie-list-body').html(data.comingsoon);

                $('.lazy').lazy({
                    combined: true
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my opinion you should just use that JSON file. However, if you still want to use JSDOM following are some of the approaches.

Given that the site requires resource processing, if you want to parse the whole page using JSDOM you will have to pass the options as mentioned in the JSDOM [documentation](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) as follows:

```
const options = {
  contentType: "text/html",
  includeNodeLocations: true,
  resources: "usable",
};
let dom = new JSDOM( data, options ).window.document;
```

These options will allow the JSDOM to load all the resources including jQuery that will in-turn allow the Node to make the AJAX call, populate the element and then in-theory you extract the links. However, there are some CSS files that JSDOM is unable to parse.

Therefore, I think your best bet is to do something along the following lines:

```
const { default: axios } = require("axios");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");

(async () => {
    try {
        const data = await axios.get(
          "https://www.cgv.id/en/loader/home_movie_list"
        );
        const base_url = 'https://www.cgv.id';
        var dom = new JSDOM(data.data.now_playing).window.document;
        var lists = [ ... dom.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].children ]
        var list = lists.map( list => [  base_url+list.firstChild.href, list.firstChild.firstChild.dataset.src ] );
        console.log( list );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})()
```

Note:
There is only one catch with the approach mentioned above which is that if the author of the website changes the endpoint for the JSON file, your solution will stop working.